# perl script to check if log updating corresponding to current time

Tags: perl

I have a job running which is generating a log file. Each line of log starts with the time it is updated.

I want to compare the time in the last line of the log with the current time of the machine. If the difference is less than 45 minutes then it will continue to run and monitor, if the difference is 45 minutes or more than that it would exit with RC1 and send a mail.

In the code below in the if condition where I wrote help required "I need specifically to compare the time in the last line of log and the actual time of machine."

Now I need three things here:

1. Each line of log starts with time it is updated, so when script reads from log in the if condition, the date and time I want it to remember only the date and time of last line.
2. second would be the comparison of that last date and time with current time on machine.
3. And third would be to check if the result of step 2 is less or equal to 45 minutes and do continue checking in loop, if not then exit.

Please let me know in case any more details required.

This is what I have written so far

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# need this to send emails via SMTP server
use Net::SMTP;
use File::Glob;

# SMTP Server Name - PHX-PDC SMTP
my $sSMTPServerName = 'name-of-server.working.checked';

# print usage error
if ( $#ARGV != 0 ) {
    print "Usage Error: scriptname.pl <HRM|FIN> \n";
    exit 4;
}

if ( $ARGV[0] ne "XXX" && $ARGV[0] ne "XXX" ){
    print "ERROR: Invalid argument.\n";
    print "Usage Error: scriptname.pl <XXX|XXX> \n";
    exit 5;
}

# get environment from command line
my $sApp = $ARGV[0];

# get todays date in YYYYMMDD format
my @aToday=localtime(time);

# get the date in yyyy.mm.dd format
my $sToday = sprintf ("%04d.%02d.%02d", $aToday[5]+1900, $aToday[4]+1, $aToday[3]);

# getting the env variables from bat file
my $sScriptName = "name-of-script";

# make path to log file
my $sOutLogFile = "$sXXLOG\\$sApp$sScriptName.$sToday.log";

# open logfile for writing
open(OUTLOG, "> $sOutLogFile") or die("Can't open $sOutLogFile\n");

if ( $sApp eq "XXX" ) {

    # print to log file
    print OUTLOG "Starting \n";

    # search for the existence of most recent subfolder 

    opendir(DIRLIST, $svar2) or die "Can't open $svar2: $!";
    my @adirs = readdir(DIRLIST);
    closedir(DIRLIST);

    my @aRecentdir = grep(/$sToday/, @adirs);

    if ( @aRecentdir && $aRecentdir[0] ne " " ) {

        # found the recent dir, now calling  sub
        my @alist = ($svar1, $svar2, $aRecentdir[0] $svar3, $svar4);
        ABC(@alist);

        ## send the email code
        {Tested to be working fine}

        #---- End SMTP emailer code ----
    }

}

sub ABC {

    my (list of variables) = @_;

    print OUTLOG "Found the latest dir!\n";

    # search for the Successful String in the logfile 
    my $slogfile = "$svar\\$svar\\...\\xyz.log";

    if ( -e $slogfile ) {

        print OUTLOG "Found  the log file. \n";
        open(LOG,"$slogfile") or die("Can't open $slogfile\n");

        my $sLines;
        {
            local $/ = undef;
            $sLines = <LOG>;
        }

        while ( <LOG> ) {

            if ( m/^(\d\d) (\w{3}) (\d{4}) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d) .*/ ) {

                #### NEED HELP IN THIS PART #######

                my $var = "$1$2$3$4$5$6";
                print "$var\n";
            }
        }

        close(LOG);
    }   

    return 1;
}


################################
#  Send Email via SMTP function
################################

sub sendEmail {
    ## SMTP code.. tested to be working fine
}
```

Comment: Do you want advice on how to read the log file, or how to compare times, or how to send email? The question is currently too broad. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: how to compare times

Comment: What time format do you have in you log?

Comment: It would be like this "03 Apr 2016 01:14:49", and will use 24 hours format as if its 1PM then 13:00:00

Comment: Do you need to check the time written in the log, or do you just need to ensure that the file is being updated at least once every 45 minutes?

Comment: I just need to ensure that file is being updated at least once every 45 minutes.

Comment: @Borodin Have you had a chance to look this. Please help. Also please remove the hold off the question, i have edited and narrowed it down.

Comment: We can't remove the hold, we can only vote to reopen the question, which I will do if you add a *lot more* information about what you want to do. It should include at least the answers to the questions in the comments here and hopefully a lot more, including what you have tried so far. You've completely changed your question; that's why I've rolled it back. The comments don't make sense underneath a different question.

Comment: @Borodin Hey, I have  edited the question, gave more explanations with the code I have done so far.  Now please help and lemme know in case any more explanations required

Comment: @Borodin Any thing that anyone can help me with here.

Comment: @Sur: That's a really good question now; well done. I've upvoted it and voted to reopen, but that's all I can do until others agree with me. My first thought is that, instead of reading through the log file to check the last entry, you could just check the time the file was last modified. An expression like `-M myfile.log` will return a floating point number of days that says how long *before the Perl script was started* the file was last modified. If you run your check program every few instead of leaving it running then you need this value to be *45/(60 \* 24)* or 1/32 or 0.03125

Comment: @Borodin Even if we check through the time the file was last modified, I would require help how we get to know the TIME the file was last modified and how to get the difference (in minutes) from the actual time on server.

Comment: @Sur: I don't know what you're saying. *"Even if we check through the time the file was last modified ... how we get to know the TIME the file was last modified"*. Those are the same thing. The time since the file was last modified in days is provided by `-M`, so multiply that by 24 * 60

Comment: @Borodin I got you, I was asking how we get to know the difference between the time file was last modified and current time.

Comment: @Sur: Use `-M`. Please just try it instead of asking more questions. `perl -E '$age = -M "xyz.log"; say $age * 24 * 60;'`

Comment: Thanks a bunch....................

Comment: @Borodin This is actually giving me the time the file was last modified, but I still have to go with my proposed plan as(reading time from last line of log) and then getting difference when compared with current time, as I noticed that file modified time (in Date modified column in folder which file is present), is only the time when File was created and its not changing irrespective of the fact that logs are updating continuously in file.

Comment: @Borodin I tried reading the last line of log file, but unfortunately I do not have File::ReadBackwards module installed on my remote server. Any other efficient way to directly read the last line of file without reading whole file and consuming memory?